# JavaScript só funciona com o debugger do IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Olá. Estou com um código em JS que funciona perfeitamente em outros browsers, porém, no IE só funciona com o debugger (F12) ativado.

Segue um trecho do meu JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
function login(){

var checkCpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
var checkPass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
if(checkCpf == '' || checkPass == ''){
document.getElementById("confirmacao").innerHTML="<p>Você precisa informar seu CPF e sua senha para entrar!</p>";
document.getElementById("cpf").value = '';
document.getElementById("pass").value = '';
document.getElementById("cpf").focus();
}else{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }  
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){       
            var callback = xmlhttp.responseText;

            if(callback !=0)
               window.location.replace(callback);
            else{
               document.getElementById("confirmacao").innerHTML="<p>CPF e/ou senha inválidos!</p>";
            }
        }
   }

var params = $('form#login').serialize();

xmlhttp.open("POST","valida.php",false); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(params);

document.getElementById("cpf").value ='';
document.getElementById("pass").value ='';

}

};
```

Comment: Esse é todo o seu código? Geralmente isso é causado por uma chamada a `console.log` no código, mas nisso que você postou não tem...

Comment: Ja experimentou substituir o `jquery-latest.js` por uma versão estável, que comprovadamente funcione com sua versão do IE?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema! @bfavaretto exatamente, tudo o que encontrei falava sobre o `console.log`, mas como você observou, nem toquei nisso. @mgibsonbr Já mudei, obrigado pela dica, mas não foi isso que resolveu o problema!

O problema é que o ID do meu `form` era igual ao nome da função JS! Só não descobri qual a relação que isso tinha com o Developer Tools do IE. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: @Nod O ideal é que tu responda a sua própria pergunta com oque resolveu o problema e a marque como a resposta correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi, o problema era que eu tinha um form e o id dele era igual ao nome da minha função javascript. Por exemplo:

```
<form id="login" onsubmit="login()"> 
    ...
<\form>
```

E no meu JavaScript:

```
function login(){
    ...
}
```

Não consegui descobrir qual a relação que isso tem com o Developer Tools(F12) do Internet Explorer já que quando o mesmo estava habilitado a página não apresentava erros, mas após trocar o ID do meu form, tudo funcionou perfeitamente!